# How do I not allow special characters and space in react hook using yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, typescript, yup

Here's the code:

```
{
      label: "Name",
      name: "name",
      placeholder: 'Name',
      type: "text",
      rule: yup.string()
      .required('Name is a required field')
      .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, '* This field cannot contain white space and special character'),
    },
```

What I'm trying to do is to restrict the input which does not allow any special characters and whitespace.  also how to validate the input while typing in yup?

I tried to do like this:
`!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`
but I'm getting an error which is this

The argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Formik and Yup to validate and disable the submit button based on the rules , but it will not help you restrict the input , you will need to handle that in onKeyUp / onKeyPress . Sandbox link to an example using Formik and Yup for validation for the email field and using onKeyPress to restrict only a-z and A-Z for the name field

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-pike-lr5p2e?file=/src/App.js